# binary search and eps in comparisons

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, eps

I have 2 comparisons inside binary search, but I can't make an exact preference in between two underlain. I oscillate between in two samples below:

```
for (int step = 0; step < 100; ++step) {
  double middle = (left + right) / 2;
  if (f(middle) > 0) right = middle; else left = middle;
}
```

and

```
for (int step = 0; step < 100; ++step) {
  double middle = (left + right) / 2;
  if (f(middle) > eps) right = middle; else left = middle;
}
```

f is a monotonically increasing function, because even with small eps, there's a danger that the corresponding error in the binary search parameter will be much bigger. On the other hand, even if our comparison is incorrect for equal values due to rounding errors, the binary search will still converge correctly since equal values may only appear in one point and everything will be correct in points very close to it. I want to have an idea about that.

Comment: one seems to find 0 and the other finds `eps`?  What's the question?

Comment: Also, does it really need to be accurate to  .0000000000000000000000000000788860905% of max-min?  For a `double` you only need 52 loops right?

Comment: http://petr-mitrichev.blogspot.com/2011/06/binary-search-and-eps-in-comparisons.html funnily enough,this blog belongs to the guy who posted the question

Comment: @Rohan: Judging from this and his other question, I seriously doubt this is the real Petr Mitrichev.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code, you are trying to decide when the function will have a zero value. The first method is already good enough, for it is consistent with your intention. It seems that there is no need to use the second method.